# Making a simple code for fone directry on java with event handling

Tags: java

There are two classes. One is mine where i handle the events and other is main. There are 4 text fields and 3 buttons, one to add a name and a number, second to search a number by name and 3rd to clear the array list.

I'm trying to search the numbers by name, the problem is that when I add the name with number it will be added, but when I search it then it shows nothing in the text field.

This is my code where i handle three buttons, mine is the class where I handle events:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {    
    ArrayList<mine> datalst = new ArrayList<mine>();
    if (event.getSource() == b1) {
        String getn=tf1.getText();
        String  getf=tf2.getText();
        mine ob1= new mine(getn,getf);

        datalst.add(ob1);
    }

    if (event.getSource()== b2) { 
        String name=tf3.getText();

        // tf4.setText(name);   
        System.out.println("calling searching"); 
        for (int i=0;i<datalst.size();i++) {
            // System.out.println("calling searching");   
            mine s =(mine)datalst.get(i);

            if (name.equals(s.getn))    
                tf4.setText(s.getf);  
            else 
                tf4.setText("nai mila");                            

        }
    }

    if (event.getSource()==b3) {
        datalst.clear();
        System.out.println("clear all");
    }
}
```

Comment: if i  enter 4  contacts (name with numbers) then it will not give response for 1,2 and ,3 contacts and  when i search contact of 4th person it mean last then it gives correct anwer

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line: `ArrayList<mine> datalst = new ArrayList<mine>();`. You are essentially creating a new array list each time, thus, when you go to search, the array list will be empty. Moving the decleration outside the method, thus making the `datalst` an instance variable should fix the problem.

As a side note, please also consider looking into naming conventions. In Java, class names use Pascal Casing, meaning that they start with capital letters, with each word starting with a capital letter: `mine` becomes `Mine`.

Also, please give good names. `tf4`, `s`, `getf` are not good names.